How do the ESP32 and CH340C need to be connected to enable serial communication and auto-reset for boot-loading?

I have designed the following circuit - I am trying to make my own ESP32 development board. This circuit is designed so that the MOSFETS can do the auto-reset functions throughout the boot-loading sequence
However, I am unable to upload any code to the board using the Arduino IDE. I get the following error when trying to do so:
Serial port COM5
Connecting.............

A serial exception error occurred: Write timeout
Note: This error originates from pySerial. It is likely not a problem with esptool, but with the hardware connection or drivers.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

I am on the correct port, Port 5. The CH340 does correctly show up in my Device Manager list, so I am confident that the CH340 driver is installed. Using my multi-meter I can see that the IO0 and RST/EN pins are being pulled low on the boot-loading sequence. I am only trying to upload a simple script that prints to serial monitor to check that the board works. Perhaps someone can see something wrong with my circuit. Perhaps the MOSFETS I am using are not intended for this functionality. Perhaps there is something else I need to do when first flashing an ESP32.
In the Arduino IDE, I use the following settings:


My guess is you switched the BJTs in the original circuit to FETs.
As you see in the FET symbol, it has an internal (intrinsic) diode from Source to Drain, which a BJT does not have.
Which means, when DTR is high it pushes IO0 pin high throug FET, and when RTS is high it will push EN pin high through FET.
So with FETs it's impossible to control EN and IO0 pins like it is possible with BJTs.

I used the BSS138's from this CH340 example: https://circuitdbpalmately.z13.web.core.windows.net/ch340-circuit-diagram.html

@JacksonHarvey That website looks like ad-ridden AI generated garbage with pictures scraped from other webpages. You cannot expect any circuit you find on random web page to work or be correct, it's good to have some critical thinking, in case someone has malicious intents and has drawn a circuit that will e.g. fry your expensive new PC when you plug it into USB.
